# How to use google cloud storage with ADT?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cloud-datastore

Total beginner here.... :(

I am using Eclipse with ADT and Google App Engine plug in.
I have built my "awesome" android app, but now I want to save some of the data the app produces onto a cloud service so I can share it between my users.

So I am trying to do this with google services. I have incorporated in my project both Cloud Storage API and Google Cloud Datastore API, both using the GDT plug in, but that's as far as I can get  :(((( 
I know I am asking a lot, but I don't even know if it is a lot, it might be a few lines of code, at least that's what I think.

So now I need a way, through some Google API to connect to a database that "belongs" to me, and store 5 numbers there from each of my users, and share other user's numbers with each other...

Can someone take me by the hand and tell me what I need to import and what not...?

I have spend hours reading all documentation about these APIs I could find and I ended up going in circles :( either trying commands that cannot be resolved, like DataStoreService(), or simply not even finding where do I put my info to get to "my" database....

Thank you all.

Comment: Is your database remote?

Comment: It should be. I want to set it up so my android app users can store their data on it...

Comment: So you don't actually have a database in place yet? If that's the case then you need to find one that works for you and THEN start learning about and working with that specific API

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, sort of :)

Comment: I am trying to interface to either google's cloud storage api or to their datastore api, but I am lost...

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I don't have any experience working with the Google cloud data store API